# Is there a more efficient way to structure code for an upsert into PostgreSQL using Rust and diesel.rs?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm relatively new to Rust, but I have a task to port some existing data workflows into `Rust` using `diesel.rs`. They involve `UPSERT` operations on tables with thousands of rows, and often > 100 columns, into a `PostgreSQL` database.

The [Diesel.rs](https://diesel.rs/) documentation contains several [examples](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/upsert/struct.IncompleteOnConflict.html#use-excluded-to-get-the-rejected-value) covering `UPSERT` functionality. I have created a [minimal example](https://github.com/mikebirdgeneau/crispy-waddle/tree/main/src), based on the `posts` example from the [Diesel.rs Getting Started](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started) guide.

Consider the following snippet of code from this [example](https://github.com/mikebirdgeneau/crispy-waddle/tree/main/src), where we define two posts and upsert them into the database. Note that for this example with four columns, the code is quite managable; however, if we had many columns in the data-model, the `set(...)` portion of this code becomes quite lengthy:

```rs
let post_set = vec![ Post {
    id: 1,
    title: "Hello World".to_string(),
    body: "This is my first post, with some edits".to_string(),
    published: true,
},
Post {
    id: 2,
    title: "Hello World 2".to_string(),
    body: "This is my second post".to_string(),
    published: false,
}];

// Run update/insert
// this works, can it be more DRY:
let rows_affected = diesel::insert_into(posts)
    .values(&post_set)
    .on_conflict(id)
    .do_update()
    // ==== CAN THIS SECTION BE MORE DRY? ====
    .set((
        id.eq(excluded(id)),
        title.eq(excluded(title)),
        body.eq(excluded(body)),
        published.eq(excluded(published)),
        // ** MANY MORE LINES HERE FOR TABLES WITH MANY COLUMNS ** 
    ))
    // ======================================
    .execute(connection).unwrap();
```

Ultimately, this code works, but if we have lots of columns, it just feels like repetition of what is already defined elsewhere in the model / schema, and will of course mean more code to update if the schema changes in the future.

Is there a DRY (don't repeat yourself) method of writing the `set(...)` component that will achieve the same result?

#### Edit: AsChangeset

As mentioned by @kmdreko I had attempted this:

```
#[derive(Queryable,Insertable,AsChangeset,Debug)]
#[diesel(table_name=schema::posts)]
pub struct Post {
    pub id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub body: String,
    pub published: bool,
}
```

Then this:

```
let rows_affected = diesel::insert_into(posts)
        .values(&post_set)
        .on_conflict(id)
        .do_update()
        // ==== CAN THIS SECTION BE MORE DRY? ====
        .set(&post_set)
        // ======================================
        .execute(connection)
        .unwrap();
```

So this would certainly be more DRY, and is exactly what I was hoping for, but I get a compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&std::vec::Vec<Post>: diesel::AsChangeset` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:76:14
    |
76  |         .set(&post_set)
    |          --- ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::AsChangeset` is not implemented for `&std::vec::Vec<Post>`
    |          |
    |          required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `diesel::AsChangeset`:
              &'update Post
              (T0, T1)
              (T0, T1, T2)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7)
            and 13 others
note: required by a bound in `diesel::upsert::IncompleteDoUpdate::<diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<T, U, Op, Ret>, Target>::set`
```

This feels close, but I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: that is one of the many bad things about oms

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking all that is no repetition, but necessary configuration. There are situations where you want to perform different actions for different columns, so you need to have the control about that at column level. Also that closely mirrors what plain SQL does. This is also the reason why you cannot pass a vector of values there, the underlying query just expects a single value.

Now I can understand that this feels like unnecessary repetition and that you might want to have a shorter solution for this. Diesel itself does not offer that, although they might be open in adding such a thing if someone writes a proposal for a concrete API.

Independently from that you could write your own custom function that takes a tuple of columns and turns that into a tuple of `excluded` constructs. That likely requires implementing a  trait for tuples of various sizes. After that you could just pass `posts::all_columns` as argument to that function and let it generate the correct return type.